# React Navigation - Unmounting previous StackNavigator's screen when new is opened

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `React Navigation` (https://reactnavigation.org) for my React Native app for Android.

I made similar flow as is described in: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

I added SignUp and ForgottenPassword screens. App starts on SignIn screen (When not logged in) and you have option to go to SignUp screen, but here I see small problem. The previous screen (SignIn) is not unmounted and running on background. This is not big problem when using this small example but as my app will grow I will get many nested screens and I dont want all of them to be loaded on background.

Easy question: How to unload (unmount component) after I switch to different screen and load (mount) it back after I hit back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is just how mobile navigation works. The navigation stack is managed automatically by React Navigation, and it's documented [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html).
Imagine an iOS app, where you can swipe back to get to the previous screen - you can see the previous screen during the swipe. This wouldn't be possible if the component did unmount.

You can manage the navigation stack using the `navigation` prop though: see [navigation prop reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html). Using `navigation.replace` should properly unmount the component, as it's replaced by a new route and therefore is not needed anymore (if you didn't replace it with the same route, but with different parameters).